# C++ SFML Font Problems

Tags: c++, text, fonts, sfml

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "CALENDAR");

sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    std::cout << "no\n";

sf::Text text1;
text1.setFont(font);
text1.setCharacterSize(30);
text1.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
text1.setStyle(sf::Text::Regular);
text1.setString("ttestst");

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type){
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
        }
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    window.draw(text1);
    window.display();
}
```

This code isn't displaying text to the screen, and the font isn't loading, i've no idea what to do, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the path for the font you're using is incorrect? Try using an absolute path - from C:/ on windows or / on osx/linux

Comment: No luck, "C:\Coding\Fonts\Arial.ttf" didn't do anything :(

Comment: did the font file load successfully?

Comment: Are you using any IDE? i.e. in Code::Blocks, you have to put the font file in the root project directory and not inside bin where it is located, when you execute it from the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the path to the font is wrong. If you're using `"arial.ttf"`, make sure that font file is in the same directory where your program starts executing.

As @twsaef said you can also use absolute path, but not in this way:

```
"C:\Coding\Fonts\Arial.ttf"
```

This is wrong. Instead of single backslash `\` you have to use double backslash `\\`:

```
"C:\\Coding\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf"
```